# Excel: Converting mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss Am/PM to dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss in 24 Hrs format

Tags: excel, date, spreadsheet, datetime-format

I am using spreadsheet and not microsoft excel. I need help in converting below format which should be able to use below formulae in spreadsheet

```
A1-TRUNC(A1) : to retrieve TIME for this.

8/16/2017 5:15:00 PM
to 
8/16/2017 17:15:00
```

I tried using format option, Data/Text to Columns/MDY also used formulae like

> =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".pm",""),".",":")+(12/24) but of no help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function in a VBA Module:

```
Public Function showHours(myDate As Date)

ActiveCell.Value = Format(myDate, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")

End Function
```

Then in, for example, cell A2 enter = showHours(A1)

Comment: Sorry, not aware of VBA. Could you please provide a solution which can applied in spreadsheet

Comment: Try using TEXT function in cell A2 = TEXT(A1, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")